# Fill up a table cell completely with any number of equally wide buttons in CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width

I have a (simplified) HTML structure like this:

```
<div class="table">
    <form class="tr">
        <span class="td">
            <input type="submit" value="Button 1"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Button 2"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Button 3"/>
        </span>
    </form>
</div>
```

The submit buttons inside are generated dynamically on server-side with JSP, so their number may vary, normally in the range 1-3.

Here's the simplified CSS I have so far:

```
.table {
    display: table;
}
.table .tr {
    display: table-row;
}
.table .tr .td {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.table .tr .td input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
}
```

However, setting the buttons' `width=100%` makes each button as wide as the cell, causing them to wrap and display next to each other vertically.

What I want is to expand the width of all buttons so that they fill up their containing cell, but all buttons in one cell shall have the same width. This has to work for varying numbers of buttons per cell and I want a solution that does not rely on JavaScript.

Here's another visualization of how I would like it to look:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| [  Button 1  ] [     B2     ] [   Btn. 3   ] |
+----------------------------------------------+
| [      Button A      ] [      Button B     ] |
+----------------------------------------------+
| [           only one wide button           ] |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: How many per line MAX?

Comment: @AllDani Normally in the range 1-3, as I said. Not sure if I might need to add more in the future yet.

Comment: Flexbox is the only thing that comes to mind, but JavaScript has better cross browser compatibility and support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox  **VS**  http://caniuse.com/#search=javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect case for a `flexbox`- apply `display: flex` to your `td`:

```
.table .tr .td {
  display: flex;
}
```

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}
.table .tr {
  display: table-row;
}
.table .tr .td {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.table .tr .td input[type=submit] {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <form class="tr">
    <span class="td">
            <input type="submit" value="Button 1"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Button 2"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Button 3"/>
        </span>
    <span class="td">
            <input type="submit" value="Button 1"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Button 2"/>
        </span>
    <span class="td">
            <input type="submit" value="Button 1"/>
        </span> 
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution did not directly work, because I need my `.td` elements to have `display:table-cell`, otherwise all cells get aligned vertically instead of in rows and columns. However, you got me on the right track. I now wrapped the content of each `.td` element in a `<span style="display:flex">...</span>` instead of directly changing the `display` style of my `.td` element. That works as intended now.